# coreui custom components and mobile version logo

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, core-ui

I am using https://coreui.io/ free react admin template version 4. Where should we put our own components (that fetch data etc.)? In /src/components or /src/views? All existing components like Dashboard are in /src/views folder.

Also how do I change the logo displayed in mobile version? Modifying `<CSidebarBrand />` in /src/components/AppSidebar.js affected only the logo displayed in desktop version. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create a new folder named `container` under the `src` folder where you can create all feature-specific files which perform tasks like fetch data and perform operations on it and render your existing component were you created in `/src/views`.

- `/src/container/feature1Container.js`
- `/src/container/feature2Container.js`
- etc...

2. In the sidebar logo, if you are asking about sidebar brand logo, then you might be using coreUi class for brand logo which is `c-sidebar-brand-full`, you can add another logo (**Mobile Version**) and add class `c-sidebar-brand-minimized` which shows in **Mobile Versions**

**Example**

```
<CSidebarBrand className="d-md-down-none" to="/">
    <span className="c-sidebar-brand-full">
      /*Logo for web version */
    </span>
    <span className="c-sidebar-brand-minimized">
      /*Logo for mobile version */
    </span>
</CSidebarBrand>
```